# Android Studio access translated strings with variable

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm programming an application that communicates with a server.
If there's a certain error, the server returns a definded errorCode.
To prompt this error to the user I need to translate the errorCode into the correct language.
I have the xml with english and german translations.

I thought, I could just refer the strings like this:

```java
    final String errorCodeId = pErrorCodeId;
    String errorCode = getString(R.string.errorCodeId)
```

I'm just looking for an easy way to access these translated strings, but I have no idea, how to do it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a mapping `errorCode` -> `R.string.errorCode*` constants. Then use this mapping to get `R.string.errorCode*` constant from `errorCode`. And then use [getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) to get String with correct translation.

Note that Android will automatically select correct translation based on user locale.

So, mapping will be something like:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> errorCodeMapping = ImmutableMap.<Integer, Integer>builder()
    .put(1001, R.string.errorCodeDenied) 
    .build();
```

And then use:

```
if (errorCodeMapping.get(errorCodeFromServer) != null) {
   String description = getString(errorCodeMapping.get(errorCodeFromServer));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Resources class for this purpose.

```
 int id = getResources().getIdentifier(errorCodeId, "string", getPackageName());
```

where id is the resource id of the localized string. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you can find the documentation

Comment: allright, perfect. But I've got the id, because the server returns it and I need the corresponding string to this id. Can you give an example for that case?

Comment: I thought you had already your mapping server_error_id -> localized string in your xml file

Comment: yup, that's right :D The errorId returned by the server is the `<string name="erroridstandshere">xyz</string>` I just haven't found a way to access this string from my code with the errorid, because this is returned from the server while the app is running.

Comment: `erroridstandshere` is `errorCodeId`. You have to use `getIdentifier` to retrieve the id of the localized string. After that you can use getString with the returned id